# Sorting nested dictionary according to a key

Tags: python, dictionary

i have a dictionary as below :

```
{' PLATINUM': [{'Name': 'MATH',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 50 Rs per year',
   'value': 50},
  {'Name': 'SCIENCE',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 100 Rs per year',
   'value': 100},
  {'Name': 'TOTAL',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 200 Rs per year',
   'value': 200},
  {'Name': 'SOCIAL',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 50 Rs per year',
   'value': 50}],
 'TITANIUM': [{'Name': 'SOCIAL',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 20 Rs per year',
   'value': 20},
  {'Name': 'MATH',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 10 Rs per year',
   'value': 10},
  {'Name': 'TOTAL',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 30 Rs per year',
   'value': 30}]}
```

I wanted it to be sorted at each level - 'PLATINUM','TITANIUM' (as many levels) with the 'value'.
so expected dictionary will look like :

```
{' PLATINUM': [
  {'Name': 'TOTAL',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 200 Rs per year',
   'value': 200},
  {'Name': 'SCIENCE',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 100 Rs per year',
   'value': 100},
  {'Name': 'MATH',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 50 Rs per year',
   'value': 50},
  {'Name': 'SOCIAL',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 50 Rs per year',
   'value': 50}],
 'TITANIUM': [ 
  {'Name': 'TOTAL',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 30 Rs per year',
   'value': 30}
  {'Name': 'SOCIAL',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 20 Rs per year',
   'value': 20},
  {'Name': 'MATH',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 10 Rs per year',
   'value': 10}]}
```

Can any one help me to achieve it with python code ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i created the dictionary with code from a csv, but really not able to go ahead with the expected dictionary format ?

Comment: Have you tried anything to sort it, or do you just want us to write your code for you? Usually a good question has a small portion of the code you're working on highlighting where you're stuck, and including any errors you're getting and can't resolve.

Comment: Start reading something like this https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/09/how-to-sort-python-dictionary-by-keys/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following dictionary comprehension, where the inner dictionaries are [`sorted`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/sorted.html) according to the key `value`:

```
from operator import itemgetter 
d = {' PLATINUM': [{'Name': 'MATH', 'Description': 'You ...'}

{k:sorted(d[k], key=itemgetter('value'), reverse=True) for k in d}
```

---

**Output**

```
{' PLATINUM': [{'Name': 'TOTAL',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 200 Rs per year',
   'value': 200},
  {'Name': 'SCIENCE',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 100 Rs per year',
   'value': 100},
  {'Name': 'MATH',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 50 Rs per year',
   'value': 50},
  {'Name': 'SOCIAL',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 50 Rs per year',
   'value': 50}],
 'TITANIUM': [{'Name': 'TOTAL',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 30 Rs per year',
   'value': 30},
  {'Name': 'SOCIAL',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 20 Rs per year',
   'value': 20},
  {'Name': 'MATH',
   'Description': 'You can earn up to 10 Rs per year',
   'value': 10}]}
```

Comment: If what's below is the output of your code, then the answer is wrong since the expected output is different from yours